# How to use gomobile to release output non debug apk?

Tags: android, gomobile

So I am running `gomobile build -target android -o someapk.apk github.com/user.project`

And keep getting debug apks, is there any way for me to get a production apk.

Initially I was working with https://github.com/hajimehoshi/ebiten and trying to implement an basic android app using the instructions given and was banging my head against the wall. So I decided to use gomobile build and was wondering how to get a non-debug version.

Thanks, I tried inserting an AndroidManifest file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like for ebiten you can use ebitenmobile which can handle these sort of problems

https://ebiten.org/mobile.html